# Cambiar estado de boton

Tags: bootstrap, botón

quisiera saber como puedo cambiar el estado del boton

```
</div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="input-group ing-ci">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" aria-describedby="button-addon4" id="nombre">
            <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" type="button" id="editar_usuario"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="agregar_usuario"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" type="button" id="confirmacion" name="confirmacion"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>




$('#agregar_usuario').click(function () {
     $(".confirmacion").attr("disabled",false);
  
});
```

cuando doy click en agregar usuario quiero se active el boton confirmacion, pero no funciona, tambien intente con prop pero nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu etiqueta `div` no tiene la clase confirmación, por eso no sucede nada ya que jQuery no la encuentra en el DOM

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" type="button" id="confirmacion" 
 name="confirmacion"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
```

Con jQuery estas llamando mediante `$(".confirmacion")` a una etiqueta tenga como clase `confirmacion` y tu etiqueta no la tiene, puedes modificar tu etiqueta agregándole la clase
confirmacion o simplemente llamarla por su id, en tal caso seria asi:

```
$('#agregar_usuario').click(function () {
$("#confirmacion") //aqui reemplaze una clase por un id
.attr("disabled",false);
});
```

Comment: Gracias funciono, aunque tambien tenia el problema de que cuando refrescaba con f5 quedaban disabled y por eso no cogian